# Sorting an object ArrayList by an attribute value in Java

Tags: java, sorting, object, arraylist

I have `ArrayList zombie`, which is populated with an object called `Zombie`. `Zombie` has the attributes `health`, `x`, `y`. How would I sort the array in ascending order, using the attribute `x` of `Zombie`, which is set to initially have random values?

I have already found a possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310014/sort-an-arraylist-base-on-multiple-attributes) to my problem, but I do not understand the syntax of the answer. Explaining that answer may help, also.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You want to use [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) in conjunction with a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Zombie>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Zombie z1, Zombie z2) {
        if (z1.x() > z2.x())
            return 1;
        if (z1.x() < z2.x())
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Essentially, a `Comparator` is a key that signifies how a list should be ordered via its `compare` method. With the `Comparator` above, we consider `z1` to be *greater* than `z2` if `z1` has the higher `x` value (and we show this by returning `1`). Based on this, we sort `list`.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation and answer, but can you go more in-depth into the meaning of everything? If you could explain each line of code to me, and explain what exactly is going on, that would be most helpful.

Comment: So incredibly ugly, but it works. This looks like the only way to do this type of sort (similar answer all over the web).

Comment: why did you use 2 ifs, and not an else-if?

Comment: @orrymr It doesn't matter in this case because of the `return`; you could do it either way.

Answer (score 7):

using JAVA 8 do this:

```
zombie.sort((Zombie z1, Zombie z2) -> {
   if (z1.x() > z2.x())
     return 1;
   if (z1.x() < z2.x())
     return -1;
   return 0;
});
```

List interface now supports the sort method directly

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I found it to be usefull.

```
zombie.sort((Zombie z1,Zombie z2) -> (Integer.compare(z1.x(),z2.x())));
```

works too.

Answer (score 0):

### Java-8 solution using [Stream API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html):

```
List<Zombie> sorted = zombie.stream()
                            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Zombie::getX))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If `x` is of type `int`, the idiomatic way is to use [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-).

```
List<Zombie> sorted = zombie.stream()
                            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Zombie::getX))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### If you want to sort the original list, `zombie` itself:

```
zombie.sort(Comparator.comparing(Zombie::getX));
```

If `x` is of type `int`, the idiomatic way is to use [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-).

```
zombie.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Zombie::getX));
```